# How to incorporate JButtons into graphics?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jbutton

I'm trying to program an online version of the board game RISK. and I would like to place JButtons on the board. So basically I want JButtons on top of some images, however I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
 public void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("RISK");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);
    JButton button = new JButton("test");
    button.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 150);
    panel.add(button);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new graphics());
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    try{
      BufferedImage board = ImageIO.read(new File("board.jpg"));
    }catch(IOException e){}
    g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, null);
 }
```

Thank you very much in advance. 
 - your answer does not need to refer to this specific code, just a general example with graphics and JButtons would be amazing!

Comment: *"board game RISK"*  Like [this](http://tformers.net/i/r/Risk_M/RiskBoard.JPG)?  If that does not convey some aspect of the desired design, add those quoted words as search terms in your favorite search engine that supports image search, and find one that does.  It would be most helpful to explain the required GUI.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `paintComponent(Graphics g) {.. BufferedImage board = ImageIO.read(..`  Don't attempt to read images within the paint methods, and don't block the paint method with long running tasks.  The image should be read before then, and cached as a class attribute. 3) `frame.setSize(800, 600);`  Set the preferred size of the components (if need be) rather than the size of the frame.  4) `button.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 150);`  **Use Layout Managers!**

Comment: 5) `frame.add(new graphics());` Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently. 6) `catch(IOException e){}`  Don't do that, especially in code that 'does not work'.  Use `catch(IOException e){ e.printStacktrace(); }` instead. 7) `g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, null);` I'd be willing to bet that a `graphics` object is an `ImageObserver`.  So that should be `g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: JButtons will not work well in this situation given your need for an irregular border. Better to simply display an image on a jlabel and give it a MouseListener.

Comment: *"need for an irregular border."*  Does it?  Are the 'countries' seen in that linked image supposed to act as buttons?  I'm still unclear on how this GUI is supposed to look or behave (as if that was not patently obvious).

Comment: [maybe yes, maybe not](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/TranslucentButton.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can add images on button if your wish is that. Here is an example code.

```
BufferedImage myPictur =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/shoppingicon.png"));
JButton shoppingButton = new JButton("Shopping",new ImageIcon(myPicture));
```

Comment: No, I want to have graphics and JButtons together, for example: to have a button, and right beside it have a rectangle made by the paint method.

Comment: If you want you can add JLabel right beside to JButton and add image to the JLabel.It is just like the code in the example.

Answer (score 3):

First of all for online applications specially web, Swing will not work as it is designed for desktop applications. If you would like a Swing like web application then use

- Java Web Start
- JApplet
- GWT

now for the botton to contain a background image use:

```
BufferedImage buferedImage;
JButton buttonImage;

buferedImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("button-image-1.jpg")); 
buttonImage = new JButton("Start", new ImageIcon(buferedImage));
```

Comment: *"First of all for online applications specially web, SWING will not work as it is designed for desktop applications."*  1) It is 'Swing'. 2) Never heard of a `JApplet`? 3) Even a Swing based `JFrame` that is not launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can easily act as the client-side consumer of a web-app.